# Proving Moment Generating Function Inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality, probability-distributions, proof-explanation, moment-generating-functions

I am working through *High Dimensional Statistics* (Wainwright) and am stuck at 2.14, trying to show that a random variable $X$ is sub-exponential. The context is as follows:

> **Definition of Sub-Exponential**
> A random variable $X$ with mean $\mu = \mathbb{E}[X]$ is defined as sub-exponential if there are non-negative parameters $(\nu, \alpha)$ such that:
> $$\mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda(X-\mu)}] \leq e^{\frac{\nu^2\lambda^2}{2}} \;\;\;\;\;\; \text{for all } |\lambda| < \frac{1}{\alpha}$$
> **Example**
> Let $Z \sim  \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$, and consider the random variable $X = Z^2$. For $\lambda < \frac{1}{2}$ we have:
> $$\mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda(X-1)}] = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\lambda (z^2 - 1)} e^{\frac{-z^2}{2}}dz$$
> $$ = \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{\sqrt{1 - 2 \lambda}}$$
> Following some calculus, we find that:
> $$\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{\sqrt{1 - 2 \lambda}} \leq e^{2\lambda^2} = e^{4\lambda^2/2}, \;\;\;\; \text{for all } |\lambda| < \frac{1}{4} \tag{2.14}\label{2.14}$$
> Which shows that $X$ is sub-exponential with parameters $(\nu, \alpha) = (2,4)$.

I am struggling to prove the inequality in 2.14. I have been able to derive the the left hand side, and have created some plots to show that it is indeed true, but I don't have the intuition for *how the author arrived at it*. In other words, I am trying to figure out the intuition, thought process, and steps to take when trying to prove something like this.

I have tried to look at the taylor series expansion of the left hand side, but again don't see how the author made the leap to compare it with $e^{2\lambda^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

The logarithm is $-\lambda-\tfrac12\ln(1-2\lambda)=2\lambda^2+O(\lambda^3)$, with all $o(\lambda^2)$ terms having positive coefficient.

Comment: Ah that makes sense! I do have a follow up question though: Once we exponentiate the RHS of the equation above won't we have $e^{2\lambda^2 + O(\lambda^3)}$? And shouldn't that subsequently mean that: $e^{2\lambda^2 + O(\lambda^3)} \geq e^{2\lambda^2}$, since $O(\lambda^3)$ is positive? I am not sure how we end up proving that the LHS of 2.14 is $\leq e^{2\lambda^2}$.